# What's the difference between having "@babel/core" and "babel-core" in your package.json file?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, babeljs, package.json

Is there any difference between having one or the other in your package.json file?

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "babel-core": "^7.3.4"
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@babel/core is the scoped package structure that was introduced in v7, so from v7 this is the only correct way to reference the package. babel-core is used in prior versions